# undefined variable $parser using s9e\TextFormatter

Tags: php, text-formatting

**Edit**: This is NOT a general question about undefined variable but about this specific code example that pulls variable without specifying from where.

I'm trying to setup an HTML whitelist of tags as documented [here](http://s9etextformatter.readthedocs.io/Plugins/HTMLElements/Synopsis/) using  *s9e\TextFormatter*.

Here is my code:

```
use s9e\TextFormatter\Configurator;

function htmlFormat( )
{
    $configurator = new Configurator;
    $configurator->plugins->load( 'HTMLElements' );

    $configurator->HTMLElements->allowElement( 'b' );
    $configurator->HTMLElements->allowAttribute( 'b', 'class' );
    $configurator->HTMLElements->allowElement( 'i' );

    // Get an instance of the parser and the renderer
    extract( $configurator->finalize() );

    $text = '<b>Bold</b> and <i>italic</i> are allowed, but only <b class="important">bold</b> can use the "class" attribute, not <i class="important">italic</i>.';
    $xml = $parser->parse( $text );
    $html = $renderer->render( $xml );
}

htmlFormat();
```

However the variables `$parser` and `$renderer` are never defined in that sample code. I don't know how to integrate them in this code, do you?

Comment: `$parser` & `$renderer` could be anything. Perhaps review the code where you copied this from to understand what those variables really are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: it's not a general question about undefined variable but about this specific script.

Comment: Looking at [this example](https://github.com/s9e/TextFormatter/blob/master/docs/examples/01_verbose.php) `$parser` is apparently defined by the call to [extract()](http://php.net/extract) on line 59

Comment: Are you seeing an error in your IDE/output or just noticing that they are undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
extract( $configurator->finalize() );
```

defines those variables. This is because [extract()](http://php.net/extract) will "*Import variables into the current symbol table from an array*"<sup>[1](http://php.net/extract)</sup> (referring to [the PHP documentation example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php#example-5635) might help with understanding this). Look at the docblock for [Configurator::finalize()](https://github.com/s9e/TextFormatter/blob/master/src/Configurator.php#L223):

> ```
> /**
> * Finalize this configuration and return all the relevant objects
> *
> * Options: (also see addHTMLRules() options)
> *
> *  - addHTML5Rules:    whether to call addHTML5Rules()
> *  - finalizeParser:   callback executed after the parser is created (gets the parser as arg)
> *  - finalizeRenderer: same with the renderer
> *  - optimizeConfig:   whether to optimize the parser's config using references
> *  - returnParser:     whether to return an instance of Parser in the "parser" key
> *  - returnRenderer:   whether to return an instance of Renderer in the "renderer" key
> *
> * @param  array $options
> * @return array One "parser" element and one "renderer" element unless specified otherwise
> */
> ```
>
> <sup>[2](https://github.com/s9e/TextFormatter/blob/master/src/Configurator.php#L223)</sup>

Those last two options (*returnParser* and *returnRenderer*) default to true.

Try running these lines (after configuring the Configurator instance):

```
extract( $configurator->finalize() );
echo 'typeof $parser: '.get_class($parser).'<br>';
echo 'typeof $renderer: '.get_class($renderer).'<br>';
```

This should yield this text:

> typeof $parser: s9e\TextFormatter\Parser
>
> typeof $renderer: s9e\TextFormatter\Renderers\XSLT

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://php.net/extract</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>https://github.com/s9e/TextFormatter/blob/master/src/Configurator.php#L223</sub>